# Double iteration to a list python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iteration, list-comprehension

```
for x in range(0,img_row):
    for y in range(0,img_col):
       img_lst.append([img[x,y][0],img[x,y][1],img[x,y][2]])
return img_lst
```

How do I use list Comprehension here?

```
img_lst = [img[x,y][0], img[x,y][1], img[x,y][2] y for y in range(0,img_col) for x in range(0, img_row)]
```

I tried this but it is giving my invalid syntax and when I remove "y" in the beginning it gives me that Y is not defined

the whole function:

```
def cvimg_to_list(img):
    img_row = img.shape[0]
    img_col = img.shape[1]
    img_lst=[]

    img_lst = [img[x,y][0], img[x,y][1], img[x,y][2] y for y in range(0,img_col) for x in range(0, img_row)]
    return img_lst
```

Comment: `...img[x,y][2] y...`  this seems wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert nested loops with a `list.append()` call to a list comprehension, all you have to do is move everything between the `.append(...)` parentheses to the front, remove the `:` colons after the `for` loops, and finally add `[...]` around the result:

```
[
[img[x,y][0],img[x,y][1],img[x,y][2]]
for x in range(0,img_row)
    for y in range(0,img_col)
]
```

Note that the order of the `for` loops *does not change*!

This can then be put onto one line; I added some whitespace for readability and simplified the `range()` calls:

```
[[img[x, y][0], img[x, y][1], img[x, y][2]]
 for x in range(img_row) for y in range(img_col)]
```

Because you build a new list with the first 3 values from `img[x, y]`, you can also use slicing:

```
[img[x, y][:3] for x in range(img_row) for y in range(img_col)]
```

You made three mistakes in your attempt; you swapped the order of the `for` loops, you added in an extra, stray `y`, and you dropped the `]` closing bracket for the list object you produce each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure about what are you trying to achieve, but if my assumption is correct (you want to get a list of pixel values values from the three channels of an image that you opened with opencv), you can use numpy to do this.

```
img_lst=img.reshape(-1,3).tolist()
```

Bearing in mind that cv2 loads images as BGR and not RGB.

*note: not being properly an answer to the question, I would have rather post this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation for that*

Comment: Please consider the limit to comments was put there for [general purposes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) and even if you mean well, using an answer to circumvent that may not be well received. In this case, if the OP is just looking for any way to reduce the image to a list, your post has a merit **as an answer**, but if they are interested in explicitly writing the comprehension lists, well...